# Doctrine Relationships .. Cant figure it out

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Im trying to establish 2 entities with a relation, but the relation is slightly different from each angle, so ..

im trying to do it so  a show can have multiple quotes .. but from the quote there is only 1 show linked.

So its like a OnetoMany show and a OneToOne in the quote .. is that possible?

Then in my show I can get $show->getQuotes() to retrieve all the quotes    but from inside a quote I can then do a simple $quote->getShow() to get the linked show to that quote

Hope someone can help me get my head around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats sounds like a default OneToMany relation. Your entities should look like below. Quotes is a collection in Show with multiple entries, and a quote has a getter for getShow() that returns a Show-object.

```
class Show{

   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->quotes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

/**
* @ORM\Id
*/
private $id;


/**
* One Show has Many Quotes.
*
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Quotes", mappedBy="show")
*/
private $quotes;
}


class Quotes{

/**
* @ORM\Id
*/
private $id;


 /**
 * Many Quotes have One Show
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Show",inversedBy="quotes")
 * @JoinColumn(name="ID_SHOW", referencedColumnName="ID")
 */
private $show;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much .. I struggle so much trying to figure out relationships!

Comment: You might want to accept it as answer then :-) , also you are welcome!